# Define the right Firestore Security Rules

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

Im new to Firebase Firestore and I want to define the security Rules.
My datastructure is very simpel as you can see in the picture.

[image: data structure]

Every user has his own document with subcollections.
I want that a user can only read and write his own documents (including documents in subcollection), so my rules should look something like this:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, update, delete: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow create: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

With this code, will the user be able to read and write documents in subcollection too?
Is there anything else thats important what I need to add to the security rules or is this all I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `match` statements in your rules control what those rules apply to. In your case the:

```
match /users/{userId} {
```

This rule applies to the documents in the `users` collection itself, and not to the documents in subcollections.

---

If you want to apply the same rule to all subcollections too, you can use a [recursive wildcard match](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#recursive_wildcards) (`=**`) like this:

```
match /users/{userId=**} {
```

Not with this, the same rule apply to the documents in the `users` collection, and all subcollections/documents under there.

---

You can also more granularly control access to subcollections, by nesting the `match` clause for them. For example, say you have a subcollection `messages`, and you only want to allow the user read access to that subcollection, you can accomplish that with these rules:

```
match /users/{userId} {
  allow read, update, delete: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
  allow create: if request.auth != null;
  match /messages/{messageId} {
    allow read: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
  }
}
```

As you can see, we're repeating the conditions verbatim here, so it's common to capture conditions in [custom named functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#custom_functions) to improve readability and maintainability.

Comment: Thank you, so in my case I just need to use ''match /users/{userId=**} {'' and a user is only allowed to read and write in his document and also in his subcollection documents?

Comment: Yes, if you want to apply the same rule to all subcollections too, you can use a recursive wildcard match (`=**`).

Comment: Using the code `match /users/{userId=**} {` didnt worked for me. When calling `request.auth.uid == userId` I got false. Instead I needed to use `match /users/{userId}/{documents=**} {` Is this the correct way?

Comment: I don't know why the `match /users/{userId=**} {` wouldn't work, given that it is exactly how it's documented. If you still need help there, edit your question to show the updated rules - and the [minimal code that produces problems against it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and I'll have a look.

Comment: [in this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics) they use `match /users/{userId}/{documents=**} {` too. But whats the difference between this two solutions?

Comment: I don't recognize that last syntax. Even if that works, it'd functionally be the same as the `match /users/{userId=**} ` in my answer, which I do use all the time.

Comment: The issue I get with this syntax is, that in this case the userId starts with a `/` so the comparison fails. I dont know where the `/` comes from...